# how to change font and type face of webview

Tags: android, css, fonts, webview, typeface

I wanna load my custom typeface or font to the web view. so I create a html file that contains typeface and text for webview like this:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
@font-face {
    font-family: my_font;
    src: url('file:///android_asset/fonts/yekan.otf') 
}
body {
    direction:rtl;
    font-family: my_font;
    font-size: large;
    text-align: justify ;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
    my text
</body>
</html>
```

and then put this html file in assets folder and call it's like this:

```
myWebview.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/salamt_news_about.html");
WebSettings settings = myWebview.getSettings();
settings.setDefaultTextEncodingName("HTF-8");
```

All content load success fully but font won't changes. I tried many ways. I used .ttf font instead of .otf but still unsuccessfull. I think problem is with loading font path but cant find out how. 
when I changed src to: `src: url('fonts/BYekan.ttf')` It's just loads successfully in browser but not in phone.

Comment: Does it work when you open the html file with your browser?

Comment: @user3249477 It's work on browser on some situation but not in phone. I updated the question. plz check